# Redeem - different meanings - related?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, transatlantic-differences

I'm flummoxed by the various meanings on 'redeem' involving improvement or rescue (of a person) and also involving satisfaction of a debt/obligation and other financial uses. The connection between the financial set of meanings and the human-person meanings bothers me - putting people on the same level as financial instruments or raw materials or something.

Is there a way to understand those different meanings, maybe historically, or maybe related to how other languages translate those terms, that changes that dynamic?

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redeem):

> redeem [verb] re·​deem ri-ˈdēm
>
> - 1: to buy or win back
> - 2a: to free from captivity especially by paying a ransom
> - 2b: to free from the penalties of sin
> - 3: to change for the better: reform
> - 4: to remove the obligation of by payment
>
> *the government redeems savings bonds*
>
> - 5: to make good: fulfill
>
> *redeem a promise*

Comment: The literal/etymological meaning in Latin of *re-* + *emo* was "buy back"  and the other meanings are simple developments of this

Comment: The full OED lists the highly specific sense ***To reclaim (land)** for cultivation or habitation*, with many cited written instances ranging from 1671 to 1999.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The financial meaning was used by Christian theologians who described the death of Jesus Christ as the price that enabled God to "buy back" people from sin and death, i.e. free them from the penalties of sin. The word is used in a similar sense when, for example, a student who has failed a test is asked to redeem themselves (by working hard) in order to pass a second test and thus pass the subject. In this case the student's effort is the price paid to be freed from the penalty (failing the subject).